# How to expand widgets size in a frame with respect to other frames in Tkinter (Help on:Tkinter grid management)

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, gridlayoutmanager

Using Tkinter i have created 5 frames, each containing

- frame0 - `label`,`Entry box` and a `button(Enter)`
- frame1 - `label` and `list box` at the left side
- frame2 - `2 buttons(select & unselect)` at the center
- frame3 - `label` and `listbox` at the right side
- frame4 - `2 buttons(done & clear)`

  ```
   ----------------------------------------
   |                 frame0               |
   ----------------------------------------
   |            |            |            |
   |  frame1    |   frame2   |  frame3    |
   |            |            |            |
   ----------------------------------------
   |                 frame4               |
   ----------------------------------------
  ```

This is my code:

```
from Tkinter import *

def toplevelwin():

    def clear():
        return

    def select():
        return

    def unselect():
        return

    def done():
        return

    def enter():
        return

    window = Toplevel()

    frame0 = Frame(window)
    frame0.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W, padx=5, pady=5, columnspan=2)
    frame0.grid_columnconfigure(1,weight=2)
    lblentry = Label(frame0, text="Entery Box:")
    lblentry.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
    entrybx = Entry(frame0)
    entrybx.grid(row=1,column=0,sticky=N+S+E+W, columnspan=2)
    entrybt = Button(frame0, text=' Enter ', command=enter)
    entrybt.grid(row=1,column=2,sticky=N+W, padx=3)

    frame1 = Frame(window)
    frame1.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=E+W, padx=5, pady=5)
    lblshow_lst = Label(frame1, text="List Box 1:")
    lblshow_lst.grid(row=0,sticky=W)
    show_lst = Listbox(frame1)
    show_lst.grid(row=1,sticky=W)

    frame2 = Frame(window)
    frame2.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W)
    frame2.grid_columnconfigure(1,weight=1)
    selbtn = Button(frame2, text='Select', command=select)
    selbtn.grid(row=0, padx=5, sticky=E+W)
    selbtn.grid_columnconfigure(1,weight=1)
    uselbtn = Button(frame2, text='Unselect', command=unselect)
    uselbtn.grid(row=1, padx=5, sticky=E+W)
    uselbtn.grid_columnconfigure(1,weight=1)

    frame3 = Frame(window)
    frame3.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky=W, padx=5, pady=5)
    lblsel_lst = Label(frame3, text="List Box 2:")
    lblsel_lst.grid(row=0,sticky=W)
    sel_lst = Listbox(frame3)
    sel_lst.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)

    frame4 = Frame(window)
    frame4.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=E, padx=5, pady=5)
    Button(frame4, text=' Done ', command=done).grid(row=0, column=0, padx=7 ,pady=2)
    Button(frame4, text='Clear', command=clear).grid(row=0,column=1, padx=7,pady=2)
    window.wait_window(window)


root = Tk()
toplevelwin()
root.mainloop()
```

And this is how my window looks now:

[image]

**My Question is:**

- How do i expand `frame0` uptill `frame3`. ie, i want the `entry box` to extend till frame3's end having the `button(enter)` to its right side as it is.
- And i want the `bottom frame's` button(done and clear) to be placed on the right side of the window

**Tries:**

- i tried to increase the size of the entry widget, which in turn pushed frame2 and frame3 to the right side.
- used `sticky=N+S+W+E`, which pushed it to the center of the window
- also did tried `sticky=W` for the bottom frame containing 2 buttons. They moved to the center but not right

Comment: Do you really want two windows?

Comment: because you're using those frames, you could use `pack` which might make things easier. Are you interested in that solution, or are you specifically asking about how to fix problems with grid?  ie: is the question "how do I get the layout I want" or is it "what am I doing wrong with grid"?

Comment: @EricLevieil,.. it the toplevel window. I havent posted the complete code, its just the frame work of what im developing

Comment: @BryanOakley,.. first of all, im sorry if my question wasnt clear. This is just the begining of the toplevel window and i will add some other widgets as required. So i thought going for `grid` would be a better option. And more over i wanted to "how can i get the layout what i wanted" using `grid`.  Also if you come across wrong or weird code lines, plz do rectify me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using grid, to make a widget capable of expanding or shrinking, you need to
set its `sticky` parameter and set its grid cell's `weight`. [Each column and each row
of a grid has a weight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7539401/#7539500).

By default all column and row weights are 0, which mean they
will shrink to the smallest valid size.

To make it expand in the east-west direction, increase its column weight with
`grid_columnconfigure`.

To make it expand in the north-south direction, increase its row weight with
`grid_rowconfigure`.

---

So, for `frame0`,

- Use `columnspan=3` to make `frame0` span 3 columns.
- Use `sticky='WE'` to make `frame0` stick to both the west and east sides of
  its cell.
- Use `frame0.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)` to increase the grid cell's weight to 1.

For `frame4`,

```
frame4 = Frame(window)
frame4.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='E', padx=5, pady=5, columnspan=3)
```

would work by making `frame4` stick to the east side if its cell. Note that without a weight, `frame4` shrinks too; it just shrinks while sticking to the east side, so the buttons it contains end up on the right.

If you want to make `frame4` span the entire space from west to east as shown in your diagram, then use

```
frame4.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='WE', padx=5, pady=5, columnspan=3)
frame4.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
Button(frame4, text=' Done ', command=done).grid(
    row=0, column=0, padx=7, pady=2, sticky='E')
Button(frame4, text='Clear', command=clear).grid(
    row=0, column=1, padx=7, pady=2, sticky='E')
```

[image]

```
from Tkinter import *

def toplevelwin():
    def clear(): return
    select = unselect = done = enter = clear
    window = Toplevel()

    frame0 = Frame(window)
    frame0.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='WE', padx=5, pady=5, columnspan=3)
    frame0.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    lblentry = Label(frame0, text="Entry Box:")
    lblentry.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='W')
    entrybx = Entry(frame0)
    entrybx.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='NSEW', columnspan=2)
    entrybt = Button(frame0, text=' Enter ', command=enter)
    entrybt.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky='NW', padx=3)

    frame1 = Frame(window)
    frame1.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='EW', padx=5, pady=5)
    lblshow_lst = Label(frame1, text="List Box 1:")
    lblshow_lst.grid(row=0, sticky='W')
    show_lst = Listbox(frame1)
    show_lst.grid(row=1, sticky='W')

    frame2 = Frame(window)
    frame2.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='W')
    selbtn = Button(frame2, text='Select', command=select)
    selbtn.grid(row=0, padx=5, sticky='EW')
    uselbtn = Button(frame2, text='Unselect', command=unselect)
    uselbtn.grid(row=1, padx=5, sticky='EW')

    frame3 = Frame(window)
    frame3.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky='W', padx=5, pady=5)
    lblsel_lst = Label(frame3, text="List Box 2:")
    lblsel_lst.grid(row=0, sticky='W')
    sel_lst = Listbox(frame3)
    sel_lst.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='W')

    frame4 = Frame(window)
    frame4.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='WE', padx=5, pady=5, columnspan=3)
    frame4.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    Button(frame4, text=' Done ', command=done).grid(
        row=0, column=0, padx=7, pady=2, sticky='E')
    Button(frame4, text='Clear', command=clear).grid(
        row=0, column=1, padx=7, pady=2, sticky='E')

    window.wait_window(window)


root = Tk()
toplevelwin()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation for each frame

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the frames (except for the buttons at the bottom).
Juste make your widgets like that:

```
entrybx = Entry(window)
entrybx.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=N+S+E+W, columnspan=2) # columnspan= 3 better?
```

Use `sticky=W` when you want the widget on the left side of the column `sticky=W +E` for center, and `sticky=E` for right.

For the buttons at the bottom, don't forget `columnspan`:

```
frame4 = Frame(window)
frame4.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=E, padx=5, pady=5, columnspan=3)
Button(frame4, text=' Done ', command=done).grid(row=0, column=0, padx=7 ,pady=2, sticky=E)
Button(frame4, text='Clear', command=clear).grid(row=0,column=1, padx=7,pady=2, sticky=E)
```

Comment: if `frame` is not used, then how could i place the  center buttons `Select button` and  `Unselect button` one below the other and also inbetween two list boxes  as of where it is now. 
and changing `sticky=E' for the buttons at the bottom, worked. Actually i didnt give a try with `columnspan=3` for the bottom frame

Comment: @arvindh: if you put the Listboxes in row 1 with rowspan = 4 and the middle buttons on row 2 and 3?